# adobe flash as3 for android get access file from sdcard

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, android-sdcard, flash-cs6

i was made a simple video playback for android application with adobe flash using action script 3, where a flvplayback access playlist from xml file "xmlVideoPlayer.xml", and i put in folder "media/PustakaXML/xmlVideoPlayer.xml" where parent folder same with myfile.fla (project file).

can somebody help me, how to ; if i put myxml file on SDCARD on android mobile. so if i publish it, to APK, and instal on android mobile, the aplication can access  myxml file on SDCARD.

below the script on my adobe flash actionscript code.

```
import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.*;

// Set Variables
var flvControl:FLVPlayback = display;
var flvIndex:Number = 0;
var loopAtEnd:Boolean = true;

// Load XML file...
var xmlList:XML;
var xmlPath:String = "media/PustakaXML/xmlVideoPlayer.xml"; 
//HELP HERE if file put in SDCARD
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlPath));

// Receive the XML and load the first video
function xmlLoadedHandler(event:Event):void
{
// Save XML
xmlList = new XML(xmlLoader.data);
// Set video (Start)
flvControl.source = xmlList.video[0];
}
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadedHandler);

// 3. Handle video completion (load next video)
function completeHandler(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void
{
// Get next item in list
flvIndex++;

// Validate index
if( flvIndex == xmlList.video.length() ){
 if( loopAtEnd ){
flvIndex = 0;
}
else{
return;
}}
// Load next video
flvControl.source = xmlList.video[flvIndex];
}
flvControl.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

*i am sorry my English no good enough...*

Comment: i try use this code 'import flash.filesystem.File;' and 'Var xmlPath:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("media/PustakaXML/xmlVideoPlayer.xml");' to change xmlPath:string... it still not working

Comment: i try use code 'var xmlPath:String = String.userDirectory.resolvePath ( "media/PustakaXML/xmlVideoPlayer.xml" );' --- still not working...  please anyone help.... please..

Comment: i try use code `var xmlPath:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("xmlVideoPlayer.xml");
trace(xmlPath.String);' it stiil not working....